# \makeindex's "title" option from imakeidx ignored if tcolorbox' indexation is used

Tags: tcolorbox, imakeidx

The following MWE points out that, in case of:

- `tcolorbox` with its automatic indexation of the documented commands (thanks to its `documentation` library),
- an extra index (thanks to `imakeidx`'s multiple indices capability),

the `\makeindex`'s `title` option provided by `imakeidx` is ignored (the two indexes are titled "Index" despite `\makeindex[name=concepts,title=Concepts Index]`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{documentation}
\makeindex
\makeindex[name=concepts,title=Concepts Index]
\begin{document}
\begin{docCommand}{foo}{}%
  \index[concepts]{foo}%
  \refCom{foo} is foo.  
\end{docCommand}
\printindex
\printindex[concepts]
\end{document}
```

Do you see what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As default, the `documentation` libray of `tcolorbox` redefines the `theindex` environment similar to the `pgf` documentation. But, the default is easily changed by using the `index format` key. Especially, for the `imakeidx` package, the `tcolorbox` documentation recommends to use

```
\tcbset{index format=off}
```

Then, all formatting can be done by `imakeidx`.

The full code for the example is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{documentation}
\tcbset{index format=off}
\makeindex
\makeindex[name=concepts,title=Concepts Index]

\begin{document}
\begin{docCommand}{foo}{}%
  \index[concepts]{foo}%
  \refCom{foo} is foo.
\end{docCommand}
\printindex
\printindex[concepts]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed, sorry for the noise: I made numerous (torture) tests and was wrongly convinced `index format=off` made the index layout too much Spartan to my taste. In fact, I don't see real differences between `index format=pgf` and `index format=off`.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé No problem. The differences between `index format=pgf` and `index format=off` are really not very important. I used the `pgf`, because the key lists looked a little bit nicer.

Answer (score 5):

The `documentation` library redefines the `theindex` environment. I don't think it should, when packages such as `imakeidx` or `idxlayout` are loaded.

Until something is done to the library for solving the issue, you can restore the `imakeidx` definition at begin document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{documentation}

\makeindex
\makeindex[name=concepts,title=Concepts Index]

\expandafter\AtBeginDocument\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\theindex\expandafter{\theindex}%
}
\expandafter\AtBeginDocument\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\endtheindex\expandafter{\endtheindex}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{docCommand}{foo}{}%
  \index[concepts]{foo}%
  \refCom{foo} is foo.
\end{docCommand}
%\printindex
\printindex[concepts]
\end{document}
```